# Proving that the set $\{\omega: X_t(\omega)=Y_t(\omega), \text{for all t}\}$ is measurable.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $X_t, Y_t$ be stochastic processes on a common probbility space, $(\Omega, \mathcal{A},P)$. As I understand the event:

$\{\omega: X_t(\omega)=Y_t(\omega), \text{for all t}\}$

need not be measurable. However, I read on a mathematical blog that if both $X_t$ and $Y_t$ are jointly measurable, then the set is measurable. Do you know how to prove this?

**Attempt:**

Since they are jointly measurable we have that the set $K=\{(\omega, t): X_t(\omega)=Y_t(\omega)\}$ is in $\mathcal{A}\otimes \mathcal {B}([0,T]).$ Does that help us? We also have the relation

$$\{\omega: X_t(\omega)=Y_t(\omega), \text{for all t}\}=\{\omega: (\omega,t)\in K \text{ for all t}\}.$$

But is the last set measurable? Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: I don't think the statement in the blog is correct. You need some additional assumptions on the processes (right -continuity, for example) for  this  to be true.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you.